# sync downloaded git repository with bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a large repository on Bit Bucket (1GB+). When I try to clone the repository the connection breaks between 80% to 95%. Since git does not have resume option, I have to start from scratch each time.

I have tried cloning the repository 8-10 times and each time the connection broke. Finally I was able to download the repository in .zip format from BitBucket.

I now have the repository on my local machine but am unable to sync it with remote repository (BitBucket). The .zip repository does not have the hidden .git folder and therefore I had to initialize git

Following is what I have done

1. Git init
2. Git remote add origin
3. Git add .

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to push changes to the remote repository and pull recent commits?

Comment: Have you tried making a shallow clone? This may help in some circumstances. And creating new repo from zip won't provide you a tree, so you won't be able to push without forcing it.